# Is there a way to do generic DBSets in a winforms user control?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
 public class MaterialBase : UserControl
 {
      ...
      public virtual DbSet _DBSet { get; } //the entity needing to be loaded
      ...
      private DBContext DB { get; set; } //the database model we are connecting to


      private void MaterialBase_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
           grid.SetDataBinding(_DBSet.Local.ToBindingList(), null, true, true);
      }
 }
```

The problem that I am running into is "...Local.ToBindingList()" errors with the message

```
 ToBindingList is not a member of IList
```

Now, if I made the code less generic for testing purposes, I could change the problem line of code to the following and it works perfectly:

```
 grid.SetDataBinding(DB.Items_MaterialOne.Local.ToBindingList(), null, true, true);
```

Generally speaking, the intent of this is that MaterialBase is a user control that gets implemented by other more specific controls.

For a new user control example:

```
 public class MaterialOne : MaterialBase {
      public override _DBSet => DB.Items_MaterialOne; 

 }
```

The control itself just provides a common way to edit characteristics for a bunch of different materials, so literally the only thing that is different is the database entity (Items_MaterialOne) that I need to load into a grid.

So, can anyone help me out with a way to have a common/generic method of loading data into a grid via entity framework?  C# or VB is fine, and I'm not too happy with my current implementation, so new ideas are welcome.

Comment: You'd have to do it using Reflection.

Comment: "*the intent of this is that MaterialBase is a user control that gets implemented by other more specific controls*" → So make it generic. What stops you from having generic base control?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Please explain how this would be accomplished...a generic user control.  The part I struggle with is...at some point the VS designer would start breaking, because it isn't going to serialize a control in the format required by a generic...For example...MaterialBase<Items_MaterialOne>

Comment: `ToBindingList` is an extension method of `System.Data.Entity.ObservableCollectionExtensions`.